# How to count identical date in List String with flutter?

Tags: flutter

I try to count the number of the same date from a list of String.

Here is an example from MyList_date_input:

```
    MyList_date_input=[2020-09-08 11:16, 2020-09-08 08:10, 2020-09-09 21:23, 2020-09-09 21:59, 2020-09-10 07:46]


      for (var i = 0; i < MyList_date_input.length; i++) {

      ...
      ???
      ...
      stringList_date_output.add("$date,mykey:$count_date"); // I search to save 
 
     }
```

Here is my expected output from stringList_date_output.

Thank you!

```
List_date_output=[2020-09-08,mykey:2,2020-09-09,mykey:22020-09-10,mykey:1]
```

Comment: Go on adding only date part into set and then convert back to list. As set will discard duplicates, you will get list of unique dates at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for `Map`:

```
Map<String, int> countDateDupes(List<String> list) {
  Map<String, int> returnMap = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.parse(list[i]);
    String date = "${parsedDate.year}-${parsedDate.month}-${parsedDate.day}";
    if (returnMap.containsKey(date)) {
      returnMap[date]++;
    } else {
      returnMap[date] = 1;
    }
  }
  return returnMap;
}
```

Follows a full example:

```
main() {
  List<String> myListDateInput = [
    '2020-09-08 11:16',
    '2020-09-08 08:10',
    '2020-09-09 21:23',
    '2020-09-09 21:59',
    '2020-09-10 07:46',
  ];
  print(countDateDupes(myListDateInput));
  // outputs: {2020-9-8: 2, 2020-9-9: 2, 2020-9-10: 1}
}

Map<String, int> countDateDupes(List<String> list) {
  Map<String, int> returnMap = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.parse(list[i]);
    String date = "${parsedDate.year}-${parsedDate.month}-${parsedDate.day}";
    if (returnMap.containsKey(date)) {
      returnMap[date]++;
    } else {
      returnMap[date] = 1;
    }
  }
  return returnMap;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but I need to respect this format ( 2020-09-08,mykey: 2) I user replaAll to replace : by ,mykey:  but I don't succes to ad replace 2020-9-8 by 2020-09-08

Answer (score 0):

It is Simple just create `HasMap` for each date and its count. Like this

```
  HashMap map=HashMap<String,int>();
  list.forEach((element) {  // List which contain dates
      int temp=map[element];
      if(temp!=null) // if is already registered date  
      {
        map[element]=temp++; // Then it will increment the count
      }
      else // If it is new date
       {
        map[element]=1; //Then it will add the count
    }
 });
```

Note Remove time from the date before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```
List<Map<String, int>> similarDaysCounter(List<String> days) {
  var daystemp = days;

  List<Map<String, int>> daysCount = [];
  while (days.length != 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
      int counter = 0;
      for (var j = 0; j < daystemp.length; j++) {
        if (days[i] == daystemp[j]) {
          counter++;
        }
      }
      daysCount.add({days[i]: counter});
      days.removeWhere((element) => (element == days[i]));
      print(daysCount);
      // print(days);
      // print(daystemp);
    }
  }
  return daysCount;
}
```

Hope this is helpful!